# phpdoc codeigniter folder classes empty

Tags: codeigniter, documentation, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I want to use PHP Documentor on my codeigniter project. 
I installed phpdocs via pear, and I tried to use it by running the following in my application directory:

```
phpdoc -d controllers
```

All methods are commented like `docblocks`.

My result is a folder with index.html file, but when I open in I cannot enter any of my classes.  It returns me an error:

> file not found

What is more, my clasess directory is empty. Out of curosity I tried using phpdoc on my clean php file and it shows me normal documentation.

Can somebody give me instructions how to use phpdoc on codeigniter project? 
Maybe there is other software which gives similar results?

Answer (score 0):

If the classes are automatically generated by the framework, see if the docblocks contain `@internal` or `@ignore`.  If the former, then use the `--parseprivate` arg.  If the latter, you'll have to manually remove that tag.

I can't think of any other reasons why no docs would be generated.

Comment: i dont see any ignore or internal tag in my project :/

Comment: My next thoughts would be: a) if the classes are *not* in the `controllers` dir, then they would not get documented;  b) if the things that *are* in the `controllers` dir are not classes themselves, then there is nothing for phpDocumentor to actually document, aside from the files themselves.

So, for a), if the class definition files are in some other directory, you need to add that dir to your `-d` arg.

For b), if the files in `controllers` are only procedural code, not classes, then there are no "documentable code elements" available for phpDocumentor to actually document.